# Variation between custom convolution vs pytorch conv2d results?

Tags: python-3.x, conv-neural-network, pytorch

I am trying to build a custom convolution using the method shown in [pytorch unfold function](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/a01d6f01b5547a396d6e28f95538cd061e14d29a/torch/nn/modules/fold.py#L173)

The custom convolution function is given below:

```
import torch
from torch import nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
from torch.nn.parameter import Parameter
import math
from torch.nn.modules.utils import _pair


class customConv(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, n_channels, out_channels, kernel_size, dilation=1, padding=0, stride=1, bias=True):
        super(customConv, self).__init__()

        self.kernel_size = _pair(kernel_size)
        self.out_channels = out_channels
        self.dilation = _pair(dilation)
        self.padding = _pair(padding)
        self.stride = _pair(stride)
        self.n_channels = n_channels
        self.weight = Parameter(torch.Tensor(self.out_channels, self.n_channels, self.kernel_size[0], self.kernel_size[1]))
        if bias:
            self.bias = Parameter(torch.Tensor(out_channels))
        else:
            self.register_parameter('bias', None)
        self.reset_parameters()

    def reset_parameters(self):
        n = self.n_channels
        for k in self.kernel_size:
            n *= k
        stdv = 1. / math.sqrt(n)
        self.weight.data.uniform_(-stdv, stdv)
        if self.bias is not None:
            self.bias.data.uniform_(-stdv, stdv)

    def forward(self, input_):

        hout = ((input_.shape[2] + 2 * self.padding[0] - self.dilation[0] * (self.kernel_size[0]-1)-1)//self.stride[0])+1
        wout = ((input_.shape[3] + 2 * self.padding[1] - self.dilation[1] * (self.kernel_size[1]-1)-1)//self.stride[1])+1

        inputUnfolded = F.unfold(input_, kernel_size=self.kernel_size, padding=self.padding, dilation=self.dilation, stride=self.stride)
        if self.bias:
            convolvedOutput = (inputUnfolded.transpose(1, 2).matmul(
            self.weight.view(self.weight.size(0), -1).t()).transpose(1, 2)) + self.bias.view(-1, 1)
        else:
            convolvedOutput = (inputUnfolded.transpose(1, 2).matmul(self.weight.view(self.weight.size(0), -1).t()).transpose(1, 2))
        convolutionReconstruction = convolvedOutput.view(input_.shape[0], self.out_channels, hout, wout)
        return convolutionReconstruction
```

But when I try comparing it with the pytorch implementation, I do not get the exact value. The code to check for difference is provided below

```
import torch
from torch import nn
from customConvolve import customConv   
torch.manual_seed(1)

input = torch.randn (10,3,64,64)

conv1 = nn.Conv2d(input.shape[1],5, kernel_size=3, dilation=1, padding=1, stride=1 ,bias = False)
conv1_output = conv1(input)

conv2 = customConv(n_channels=input.shape[1], out_channels=5, kernel_size=3,  dilation=1, stride =1, padding = 1, bias = False)
conv2_output = conv2(input)

print(torch.equal(conv1.weight.data, conv2.weight.data))

print(torch.equal(conv1_output, conv2_output))
```

I would like to know why the variation exists and how to solve this? 
Thank you.

Comment: It’s mathematically equivalent, but not computationally equivalent unless the additions are done in the same order. Otherwise, rounding errors will almost surely yield different results. Please look at all the SO questions that ask why you don’t get exact results, and all the literature (such as “What Every Programmer Needs to Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic”) on this topic.

Comment: There was a small issue with the testing code. I had to assign the same weights and bias for verifying purposes. However, when I do that, the error is very low and this is due to the rounding error as you mentioned. Thank you.